# Create SQL query with more than one where clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to do a query with 2 `where` clauses like:

```
select * from table1 where `name` = 'paul' AND `id` = 1
```

in Laravel with Eloquent, but I don't know the correct syntax.

Answer (score 11):

Simple, use another `where`

```
Model::where('name', '=', 'paul')->where('id', '=', 1);
```

Then you may use `get()` or `first()` to fetch the row(s).

If you want to use just Query Builder(Fluent) then replace `Model::` with `DB::table('table1')->`.

**Note**

- `=` is optional here. Here you can use other operators.

**Update**

From Laravel 4.2 you can also use array:

```
Model::where([
               'name' => 'paul', 
               'id' => 1
             ]);
```

Comment: another question about queries, I want to execute in Eloquent a query something like "SELECT r.id, avg( p.puntuacio )
FROM receptes AS r, puntuacio_receptes_usuaris AS p
WHERE r.id = p.recepta_id
GROUP BY r.id" but I don't know how I could do

Comment: Can you please post this as a new question and I will answer it on my free time?

Answer (score 2):

You have to have an object that corresponds to table1.

Eloquent object:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'table1';

    ...
}
```

ORM query:

```
$user = User::where('name', 'paul')
              ->where('id', 1)
              ->first();
```

Comment: Not strictly true, you can use `DB::table('table1')` instead of an Eloquent model.  Furthermore, you need only `where` or `orWhere` for chaining (not `andWhere`).

Comment: That's true, you can do that with fluent, but he was asking for Eloquent. Fixed where, thanks for pointing.